# print character in same line playground swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, swift-playground

print character in same line

```
for i in 1...5
  {
     print(i)
  }
```

> op require like

```
12345
```

> but that print like

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

any one have solution.

Answer (score 11):

[`print`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1541053-print) accepts a parameter named `terminator` which is `\n` by default. You can pass an empty string instead to print them out in a single line:

```
for i in 1...5 {
  print(i, terminator: "")
}
print()
```

Comment: no output display..

Comment: write print() before the for loop then print 4 line 12345

Comment: I think it is a bug if you do `print()` after the loop not before it seems to work

Comment: sorry didn't see you edited your answer to that. Your answer is now working for me

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var number = ""
for i in 1...5
{
    number += "\(i)"
}
print(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var points: [String] = [] // Take Mutable Array
for i in 1...5
{
    let value = String(i)
    points.append(value)  // Add value in array
}
let str = points.joined(separator: "")
print(str)
```

Out Put

```
12345
```